# generar un lista de un diccionario dados dos valores

Tags: python, lista, bucle-for, bucles, diccionarios

hola tengo este diccionario:

```py
friends = {
    1: [11, 17, 18], 2: [3, 8], 3: [2, 4, 8],
    4: [3, 14], 5: [7, 10], 6: [], 7: [5, 9, 16],
    8: [2, 3, 10], 9: [7], 10: [5, 8, 13, 15, 19], 11: [1, 17, 18],
    12: [], 13: [10, 14, 15, 16, 19], 14: [4, 13], 15: [10, 13],
    16: [7, 13, 18], 17: [1, 11, 20], 18: [1, 11, 16], 19: [10, 13], 20: [17]
}
```

voy a generar una lista de amigos **comunes** entre dos usuarios. Elija dos usuarios cualesquiera y asigne sus identificadores a las variables usuario1 y usuario2 proporcionadas en la siguiente celda. Luego, calcule la lista de amigos comunes entre usuario1 y usuario2 y asígnela a la variable común. La lista común debe ser una lista de identificadores de usuarios, o la lista vacía si no hay amigos comunes entre ambos usuarios.

Para los usuarios 2 y 3, el resultado debería ser la lista [8].

Para los usuarios 1 y 11, el resultado debería ser la lista [17, 18].

Para los usuarios 1 y 12, el resultado debería ser la lista vacía ([]).

codigo intentado:

```py
usuario1 = 1 
usuario2 = 11 
comunes = [ ] 
for usuario1, usuario2 in friends.keys():
    comunes[(usuario1,usuario2)]=[usuario1 for usuario1 in friends[usuario1]]
```

Comment: Podrías transformar las listas en set y hacer una intersección

Answer (score 0):

Como comento Christian puedes hacerlo transformando las lista en conjuntos inmutables y luego hacer una intersección.

```
user1 = friends.get(1)
user11 = friends.get(11)

comunes = set(user1) & set(user11)
```